# Using Apache2 as proxy toward Tomcat7

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

Tomcat7 server hosts a website on my machine and I want to use Apache2 as a proxy to see it through my browser: http://localhost:8080/examples as http://localhost/examples.

I have installed Apache2 and Tomcat7, they both work on my computer.
I have loaded mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http modules

In my http_vhosts.conf file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests off 
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ServerName mathost.workstation.org
  ProxyPass /examples http://localhost:8080/examples
  ProxyPassReverse /examples http://localhost:8080/examples
  ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

In my proxy_http.conf I have:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location "/examples/">
 ProxyPass /examples http://localhost:8080/examples
 ProxyPassReverse /examples http://localhost:8080/examples
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Location>
```

It doesn't work, apache logs say "GET /examples/ HTTP/1.1" 404 207".

Comment: Any messages in error_log ?

Comment: GET /examples HTTP/1.1" 404 206

Comment: This looks like an access_log, not error_log. Messages from error_log contain an additional description what cause the error, where it was looking for non-existent files, etc.

Comment: ah ok. right. sorry. I had no messages on error logs. I solved the problem anyway. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
The problem was the path "/example/". I had to use the right url: "/example".
Then, http_vhosts.conf had 2 vhost on port 80, absolute useless.